# Python + UDP socket - can not receive any data

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ethernet

I want to receive data by using **UDP socket** in Python. I send **UDP** data from my external HW every 1 second (connected with my PC via Ethernet cable). Also I can see data in the Wireshark:

[image]

and also I can receive data in *Hercules*:

[image]

Also I can ping to my HW and get response.

**What I have already tried**

```
import socket

localIP     = "192.168.0.10" 
localPort   = 9999
bufferSize  = 1024

# Create a datagram socket
sckt = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Bind to address and ip
sckt.bind(('', localPort))

print("UDP server up and listening")
# Listen for incoming datagrams

while True:
    
    bytesAddressPair = sckt.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
    
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)
```

This can not receive any data - it stuck on **sckt.recvfrom(bufferSize)**

Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: Increase buffersize

Comment: it did not help - BTW I send only about 30 Bytes

Comment: Used f-string   clientMsg = f"Message from Client: {message}") and see what happen.

Comment: What do you mean? my code stukcs on line **bytesAddressPair = sckt.recvfrom(bufferSize)**  - no output is in *clientMsg*.
It seems like the python can not see the Ethernet port?!?

Comment: Ur port is 9999 is used SSL by IRC chat. U should change port number.

Comment: I tried e.g. 18765 port - it is the same. But the Hercules works -it can recieve and send data

Comment: data, bytesAddressPair = sckt.recvfrom(bufferSize). Can u print it?

Comment: I think am not able to print it - the **sckt.recvfrom(1024)** does not return...

Comment: One last question. Remove  keyword. sckt = socket.socket(fsocket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

Comment: unfortunatelly nothing changed. Still thank you for your help.

Comment: Disabling firewall is the solution  - now it works!

Comment: Glad you're solved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling firewall is the solution - now it works!